# How to correct a QAM time delay

Tags: modulation, demodulation, delay, quadrature

> How can you correct the anticlockwise rotation that occurs in the received constellation of a QAM system?

My only idea is to compensate the delay with an advance but this is impossible since you would have to decode the message before receiving it.

Comment: The rotation is not generally counterclockwise. What you're looking for is *phase synchronization*, and there's very many ways you do that in practice. We don't know the context of your question, so I can really only recommend you look into that term, *phase synchronization*.

Comment: See this answer I gave previously on carrier recovery for QAM: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17297/high-modulation-index-psk-carrier-recovery/38017#38017

Answer (score 1):

If this represents the received signal where $a$ and $b$ are the real and imaginary parts respectively $s(t-\Delta) \approx [a \cos{(2\pi f_o \Delta)}-b \sin{(2 \pi f_o \Delta)}] \phi(t) \sqrt{2} \cos{(2 \pi f_o t)} + [b \cos{(2 \pi f_o \Delta)} + a \sin{(2 \pi f_o \Delta)}] \phi(t) \sqrt{2} \sin{(2 \pi f_o t)}$

one can see exactly how the signal has been rotated. Therefore the rotation can be countered by introducing a sine or cosine to counteract the delay.