# Plotting Constellation Diagrams

Tags: sampling, modulation, complex, quadrature, constellation-diagram

I'm working with some IQ data from the paper [A Wideband Signal Recognition Dataset](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2110.00518.pdf). Specifcally I've been trying to plot the constellation diagram for some the modulations within the dataset, however, when plotting IvQ I get something like this:
[image]

The meta data corresponding to this IQ data/plot looks like this:

```
  "core:sample_rate": 1.0,
  "core:datatype": "cf32_le"
  "core:sample_start": 0,
  "core:sample_count": 100000000,
  "core:frequency": 0.0
  ...
  "core:sample_start": 5698546,
  "core:sample_count": 29892,
  "core:description": "PSK2",
  "core:freq_lower_edge": 0.07299524204365537,
  "core:freq_upper_edge": 0.15222540940494844,
  "west:scale": 0.9673282231372156
```

I've seen some other posts mentioning that you have to demodulate by the carrier frequency prior to plotting an IQ data constellation plot. The plot pictured has *not* been demodulated.

One problem I had was that it isn't clear to me what the carrier frequency is. I tired taking a power spectrum of the IQ data and using the largest frequency component as the carrier, but when using that frequency as the carrier I got similar results to plot pictured above.

Would anyone know:

1. Why my IQ plot looks the way it does/how I can fix it
2. How I can find the carrier frequency/sample rate

   - the meta file says frequency=0.0, but I'm not sure if that means that 0.0 is the carrier
   - the meta file says sample_rate=1.0, does this mean 1.0Hz? that seems awfully low
3. What do freq_lower/upper_edge and scale mean in the meta files

Comment: The constellation plot is made from the baseband, matched-filtered samples. If you have a passband signal, you'll have to downcovert it and filter it -- no way around that.

Comment: gotcha, the metafiles seem to imply that the signals are already at baseband (core:frequency : 0.0, unless I'm misinterpreting this value). Wouldn't this mean I could plot IvQ directly?

Comment: Not yet: as I mentioned, you very likely need to apply a matched filter (unless that has already been done), and then you need to perform symbol synchronization. In other words: the baseband signal is $s_\textrm{BB}(t) = \sum_k a_k p(t-kT)$, where the symbol rate is $1/T$ and $p(t)$ is the pulse shape. The constellation plot consists of the $a_k$ complex numbers; those need to be extracted from $s_\textrm{BB}(t)$.

Comment: The paper says: `Each of these modulations are modulated with
whitened random symbol data and in the case of single carrier
modulations (other than GMSK) use a root-raised cosine
(RRC) pulse shape filter.` Based on your comment it seems that I would have to use a RRC for $p(t)$,  but how could I figure out the symbol rate?

Comment: You could calculate it if know how many symbols are there in the signal, the sample rate, and the number of samples. Otherwise, no idea -- trial and error? The number of samples per symbol is usually between 2 and 8 or maybe 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Direct Answers to OP's Questions**

> Why my IQ plot looks the way it does/how I can fix it

The IQ plot contains frequency offsets and possibly time offsets, and has been oversampled to show many samples per symbol. To "fix it", meaning to see an expected constellation alone, the frequency and time offsets need to be removed and the result down-sampled to 1 sample/symbol with the sample at the correct time offset. See demonstration and details below with an 8PSK constellation providing further insight into this.

> How I can find the carrier frequency/sample rate the meta file says frequency=0.0,but I'm not sure if that means that 0.0 is the carrier

Yes this means the carrier is intended to be DC, this is a baseband equivalent complex signal. There is however a carrier offset which is a small remaining error in carrier frequency. So in this case with frequency=0, it means DC is the reference point.

> the meta file says sample_rate=1.0, does this mean 1.0Hz? that seems awfully low

It is common in sampled systems to normalize time to 1 sample instead of 1 second, which then results in "normalized frequencies". So all frequencies are then given in cycles/sample where $f = 1$ would correspond to the sampling rate (1 cycle/sample), or in radians/sample where $f  = 2\pi$ would correspond to the sampling rate ($2\pi$ radians/sample.)  So to convert normalized frequencies to Hz, multiply by the actual sampling rate in Hz.

> What do freq_lower/upper_edge and scale mean in the meta files

I believe this is the range of occupied bandwidth (signal power above some threshold in a spectrum plot). As explained above, multiply by these numbers by the sampling rate to convert to Hz. We see from this a hint at what the frequency offset would be, approximately, as the average between upper and lower.

**Further Details and Demonstration**

The constellation is likely oversampled (many samples per symbol) so that we see the desired symbols as they would be on the unit circle (for a PSK or phase shift keying modulation) as well as the transition samples between symbols. Further under condition of carrier offset, the entire constellation will rotate at the offset frequency. In addition, the waveform as transmitted will often be dispersed from the ideal constellation point due inter-symbol interference (ISI) as the ideal pulse shaping filter that has no ISI is typically split between transmitter and receiver to implement a "matched filter" in the receiver. Finally it is possible that the samples as received are offset in time from the correct sampling location (time offset). A typical receiver will address all these "offsets" using recovery loops (timing recovery, carrier recovery, etc). One approach to carrier recover that I demonstrate [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17297/high-modulation-index-psk-carrier-recovery/38017#38017) with an implementation block diagram which occurs after timing recovery (with the samples down-sampled to be one sample per symbol at the expected time location within each sample), is to measure the phase rotation from symbol to symbol, and use that to correct the frequency offset in a classical control loop.

For a quick post processing study, an easy way to determine the carrier offset on the current waveform as sampled is to raise the waveform to the Mth power for an M-PSK waveform. After doing this taking the FFT will reveal a stronger tone at four times the carrier offset. I demonstrate these concepts below with an example 8-PSK waveform:

The constellation for the 8PSK waveform as transmitted, without any carrier offset is shown below. I have plotted all samples in blue, and every 8th sample in orange (the waveform was oversampled 8 samples per symbol). We see the effect of intersymbol interference since the pulse shaping filter is split between transmitter and receiver :

[image: 8 PSK]

Passing this waveform through a second pulse shaping filter (in the receiver), with no time or frequency offset results in the following:

[image: 8 PSK recovered]

However, if there was a frequency offset, the entire constellation would rotate, with a small frequency offset introduced, the first constellation now appears as:

[image: 8 PSK with offset]

Raising this waveform to the 8th power (M=8) and looking at the spectrum reveals a strong tone at 8x the actual frequency offset:

[image: FFT]

This is one simple approach to determine if a frequency offset exists, and can be used as part of a recovery loop. More efficient approaches that operate sample by sample are detailed in the linked post above.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed response! I'll try the methods you suggested!